# Hadoop mkdirs fails during execution of a jar file

Tags: hadoop, jar, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am a very begineer on Hadoop. I developed a jar and tried to execute it with command below. But I got error: **Mkdirs failed to create D:...\META-INF\license**

I checked all permissions and gave full access but did not work.

command: **hadoop jar wiki-stats.jar example/data/stats.txt example/results/**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide more information. Full stacktrace of your error, the code of wiki-stats.jar (driver code at least) and your Hadoop environment information.

Comment: are you running this from Cygwin in windows?